# Is there a way for FileWriter.write() to continue writing strings after spaces in runtime?

Tags: java, filewriter

When I'm trying to run this piece,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

class  CSWrite1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
        out.print("Enter the filename\t>"); 
        String file = input.next();
        out.println("Enter the text");
        String text = input.next();  // IN:"Hello, How are you" --> "Hello,

        try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file))
        { fw.write(text); }
    }
}
```

while giving input to text as "Hello, How are you" The file is written only with "Hello,. The remaining text after the first space is not being written into the file.

Comment: Try replacing `input.next()` with `input.nextLine()`, i.e. `String text = input.nextLine();`

Comment: @Abra, Tried String text = input.nextLine();, but execution ends right after getting the prompt

Comment: Your try-without-resources block automatically closes the `FileWriter`. That's what it's for. It has no other purpose. If that's not what you want, don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CSWrite1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(in)) {
            out.print("Enter file name> ");
            String file = input.nextLine();
            try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file)) {
                out.print("Enter text: ");
                String text = input.nextLine(); // IN:"Hello, How are you" --> "Hello,
                fw.write(text);
            }
            catch (IOException xIo) {
                xIo.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, somehow using `input.nextLine()` for storing in both - file and text is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The `Scanner` is using delimiter, which includes space by default. What you could do (I do not know how elegant this is) is to remove delimiter.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
input.useDelimiter("");
String text=input.nextLine();
System.out.println(text);
```

This works for me. It is not your file writer, it is the `Scanner` that is doing this.

Comment: `input.nextLine()` worked, didn't had to use any delimiter; but I had to use nextLine() for taking inputs for both string variables as `@Abra` mentioned in his/her answer. Either one as next() is giving imporoper result. Thank you, have an upvote.